# BroadcastEvent, alarm function android

Tags: android, alarm, boot

I have run into a snag, I can't get my alarms properly setup again after a boot.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        if(fm.getAlarmBool()){
            time = fm.getAlarmTimeLong();
            reminder.startAlarm(time);
        }
    }
```

This is my method that I want to run after it boots up. I have added permissions in the android manifest but I can't get it to work. Whats wrong?

Comment: pls add some additional code cos from reminder, fm it is not possible to ans.

Comment: reminder class works with calendar to set a fixed time, for example if I set the time 15:20 then it sets a alarm event at that time, fm just writes a string to a file then fetches information from file. In this case it writes the time the event will occure. Its not needed to solve this problem in my opinon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
     context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));      
 }
```

}

in manifest

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="BootReceiver">    
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>
```

so here in your service collect all the reminders and reschedule them.
for this you can store it in shared pref or database for persistent storage

Comment: What class do I need to write on NotifactionService? The class that I want to run when the device boots up? Do you see any errors in my IF statement? When I place your code bellow onReceive method and reboot my phone the alarms actives instantly. Do I need to place this within some sort of statement?